# Помогите прорефакторить

Tags: yii2, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

Читаю документацию хочу привести код к нормальному виду.

```
/**
 * Display forms adding the sell offer
 * 
 * @param integer $id orders
 * @return mixed
 * @throws HttpException
 */
public function actionOfferSellForm($id = null) {

    $modelOfferBuyForm = new OfferBuyForm();
    $order = Order::findOne($id);
    if (!$order) {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Page not found');
    }
    $certificate = Certificate::findOne(['id' => $order->source_id]);
    if (!$certificate) {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Page not found');
    }

    if ($order->user_id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id) {

        return $this->renderAjax('/site/info', ['message' => 'Вы не можете приобрести свой сертификат']);
    }
    $modelOfferBuyForm->source_id = $order->id;
    $modelOfferBuyForm->certificate_code = $certificate->certificate_code;
    $modelOfferBuyForm->buyer_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    $modelOfferBuyForm->seller_id = $order->user_id;
    if ($modelOfferBuyForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelOfferBuyForm->validate()) {
        $modelOfferBuyForm->status = 1;
        $modelOfferBuyForm->expertise = 0;
        $modelOfferBuyForm->priced_currency = $order->priced_currency;
        if ($modelOfferBuyForm->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Заявка отправленна.');
            return $this->redirect('index');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Ошибка отправки заявки.');
        }
    } elseif (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax('offerBuyForm', ['model' => $modelOfferBuyForm]);
    } else {

        return $this->render('offerBuyForm', ['model' => $modelOfferBuyForm]);
    }
}
```

Данный код берет Сделку и ищет сертификат, после чего выполняет манипуляции. Хочется сделать более элегантно, так как `if (!$order) { throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Page not found'); } $certificate = Certificate::findOne(['id' => $order->source_id]); if (!$certificate) { throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Page not found'); }` Думаю не есть лучшая практика. ну и другие моменты типа i`f ($modelOfferBuyForm->save()) {` без валидации

Comment: что делает данный код? и что конкретно хотелось улучшить?

Comment: добавь это описание непосредственно в вопрос

Answer (score 3):

1. Если вас смущает **save** без **validate**, то это вы зря. Так как валидация все равно происходит, если только ее принудительно не заглушить `save(false)`. Если это форма унаследована от ActiveRecord, если нет, то логично, поместить валидацию в сам метод **save**
2. Валидация у вас в коде таки идет после **load**
3. Как насчет двух запросов вытащить через один с релейшеном?

   ```
   $order = Order::find()
       ->where(['id' => $id])
       ->with(['certificate'])
       ->one();
   ```
4. Вместо магических цифр старайтесь использовать константы, через месяц другой вы не вспомните.
5. При сценарии когда у вас "Ошибка отправки заявки", нет ни редиректа ни рендера.
6. Какая-то вывернутая логика. Думаю нужно пересмотреть ее в целом. Я лично не понял до конца когда экшен обрабатывается через ajax, а когда нет. Может есть смысл разнести их?